# What the alternative for UDDI Repository?

Tags: rest, soa, uddi

Dose RESTful services have some repository like UDDI for Web service?

Please tell me the URL for resist the service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for standards, the [SOA Repository Artifact Model and Protocol](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/tc_home.php?wg_abbrev=s-ramp) is basically a REST-ful replacement for UDDI.  It is based upon the AtomPub protocol.

If you are looking for products, there are plenty of tools out there that will work.  I have used [WSO2 Governance Registry](http://wso2.com/products/governance-registry/) in the past with good results.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such service I know of.

Besides, I don't know of any usable UDDI repository, too.